# Airflow dag gets stuck after renaming a task

Tags: airflow

I have a task(named `task1`) inside a subdag, a dag run has been finished. then I renamed `task1` to `task2`, and rerun the previous dag run, using 'airflow clear'. Then the subdag is always in running state. When I zoom into the subdag, I can see the subdag's state is success, and all its tasks has been finished successfully.

The subdag's log shows Airflow is still waiting for `task1`(but it is marked as 'removed'):

```
[2018-08-22 23:53:04,032] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2018-08-22 23:53:04,032] {jobs.py:2002} INFO - [backfill progress] | finished run 1 of 1 | tasks waiting: 1 | succeeded: 5 | kicked_off: 0 | failed: 0 | skipped: 5 | deadlocked: 0 | not ready: 0
[2018-08-22 23:53:04,032] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2018-08-22 23:53:04,032] {jobs.py:2006} INFO - Finished dag run loop iteration. Remaining tasks [<TaskInstance: task1 2018-08-08 15:13:02 [removed]>]
[2018-08-22 23:53:09,050] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2018-08-22 23:53:09,049] {jobs.py:2002} INFO - [backfill progress] | finished run 1 of 1 | tasks waiting: 1 | succeeded: 5 | kicked_off: 0 | failed: 0 | skipped: 5 | deadlocked: 0 | not ready: 0
[2018-08-22 23:53:09,050] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2018-08-22 23:53:09,050] {jobs.py:2006} INFO - Finished dag run loop iteration. Remaining tasks [<TaskInstance: task1 2018-08-08 15:13:02 [removed]>]
[2018-08-22 23:53:14,068] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2018-08-22 23:53:14,067] {jobs.py:2002} INFO - [backfill progress] | finished run 1 of 1 | tasks waiting: 1 | succeeded: 5 | kicked_off: 0 | failed: 0 | skipped: 5 | deadlocked: 0 | not ready: 0
[2018-08-22 23:53:14,068] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2018-08-22 23:53:14,068] {jobs.py:2006} INFO - Finished dag run loop iteration. Remaining tasks [<TaskInstance: task1 2018-08-08 15:13:02 [removed]>]
[2018-08-22 23:53:19,083] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2018-08-22 23:53:19,083] {jobs.py:2002} INFO - [backfill progress] | finished run 1 of 1 | tasks waiting: 1 | succeeded: 5 | kicked_off: 0 | failed: 0 | skipped: 5 | deadlocked: 0 | not ready: 0
[2018-08-22 23:53:19,084] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2018-08-22 23:53:19,083] {jobs.py:2006} INFO - Finished dag run loop iteration. Remaining tasks [<TaskInstance: task1 2018-08-08 15:13:02 [removed]>]
```

I'm using apache-airflow 1.8.1.
What should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

Can you recreate the error without using the sub-dag? Airflow treats each subdag as a vertex instead of a the whole graph, so when you changed the one task, it updated the subdag, but that change did not propagate back to the parent DAG.

The way Airflow handles subdags can have unintended consequences so most of the community advises staying away from them.

Comment: thank you, but I heavily depend on subdag. I cannot change it easily.

Answer (score 1):

You must change the name of the subdag. Due to how Airflow saves the information of the DAGs in the metadata db, you need to change the DAG name each time you make significant changes in the DAG.

That is why the naming convention for DAGs is `my_dag_v1`, so that you can conveniently update the `v` number each time you make changes.